# Where to put .gdbinit in Windows?

Tags: windows, gdb, mingw, gdbinit

And should it be called `.gdbinit` or `gdb.ini`?

I thought that I would try [this](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) file.

I am testing with Vectorcast, which uses MinGw. I copied the file with both names (`.gdbinit` and `gdb.ini`) to both the Vectorcast directory and it's MinGW `bin` directory, where `gdb.exe` is, as I was unsure which is `the current working directory`, but don't see anything which I would expect from that file.

So, where should I put it, and what should I call it?

Comment: Have you tried to just name it `.gdbinit` in the Vectorcast/gdb.exe directory?

Comment: As per my question - yes, I did

Comment: Can you set the environment variable `HOME` to some directory so that GDB will load `$HOME/.gdbinit` from there?

Comment: I am not running LInux. I suppose I could try on Windows, but should I set `HOME` or `$HOME`?

Comment: `HOME`, so that `getenv ("HOME")` within GDB will return this path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should put it into your `$HOME` directory or into current directory, see [How do I load .gdbinit on gdb startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15399265/72178).

You can know your home directory from gdb shell with either

```
(gdb) show environment HOME
```

or

```
(gdb) shell echo $HOME
```

You can know current directory with

```
(gdb) shell pwd
```

> And should it be called .gdbini or gdb.ini?

No, it should be called `.gdbinit`.

Comment: Alas, none of those GDB commands work in Windows. You did, however, notice a bad typo in my question (upvote for that). I had used `.gdbini` in my question, when it ought to have been `.gdbinit`. I have updated the question. The file was correctly named in both the Vectorcast directory and it's MinGW bin directory, and won't work when using that `.gdbinit` file which I linked in the question, so I am still stuck

Comment: Looks like you will get the bounty by default in a few days, but I still can't get it to work. I don't care about the bounty, no more do you, I imagine, but can you help me to get it working? Thanks

Comment: Does `.gdbinit` loading without Vectorcast? I guess it is worth to make it load without Vectorcast first. Try to set `HOME` variable to `%USERPROFILE%` and place `.gdbinit` in "C:\Users\Firstname Lastname" as suggested in mingw howto: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Set_the_HOME_variable_for_cmd_exe.

Comment: Good idea. I don't mind running GDB standalone, as opposed to launching it from Vectorcast. I will try this first thing Monday

Comment: D'oh!   For some reason, "`.gdbinit:1567: Error in sourced command file:
Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB.`"  I guess that I won't be using that `.gdbinit`; maybe I'll look for another (but what I am really looking for is [a Windows GDB GIU](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51063/gratis-portable-gdb-gui-for-windows))  Thanks for your help
(gdb)

Comment: When Creating the HOME variable in windows you may need to restart the command prompt for it to propegate.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, create a directory called anything you fancy in `c:/users/yourusername` where `yourusername` is your Windows username.

(Doesn't have to be here but it's a safe place.)

Now from the control panel invoke the environment variables dialog and create a new environment variable called `HOME`.  Set that variable to the above folder by clicking browse for folder and navigating there.

Put `.gdbinit` in there and use it to set any autoload or other behaviour as you choose.

When GDB starts it will now look in that folder for a `.gdbinit` file and load it.