# gdb Python pretty-printers not working with MinGW Windows

Tags: python, windows, gdb, mingw, pretty-print

I followed the instructions to install Python pretty-printers mentioned in the below website.
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

I checked-out the python module in my `E:\Project` directory. I created a `.gdbinit` file and replaced the path by `E:\Project\python` and finally placed the file in `C:\Users\username` folder. (I even tried placing in the current working directory `E:\Project`).

In either case, I seem to get the following message:

```
PS E:\Project> gdb .\practise
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from E:\Project\practise.exe...done.
warning: File "E:\Project\.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
        add-auto-load-safe-path E:\Project\.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "$HOME/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
        set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "$HOME/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
        info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

I tried adding the line `set auto-load safe-path /` in `.gdbinit` file, but it continued to display the same message.

There are very few posts related to pretty-printers with MinGW. The methods mentioned in the following post didn't work either.
[How do I load .gdbinit on gdb startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399265/how-do-i-load-gdbinit-on-gdb-startup/28886831)

**Can someone please help me in getting the Python pretty-printers to work with MinGW on Windows?**

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that `MinGW` version installed was not Python enabled.
To check whether the `gdb` is Python enabled, execute the following command in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) python print sys.version
```

If it does not support Python, install `MingW-W64-builds` from their website:
http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download
This version of `MinGW` supports Python.

Make sure Python 2.7 is installed on your system.
On updating the `.gdbinit` file, Python pretty-printers must work on Windows.

Comment: "Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB".- says gdb

Comment: Same in 2024. Mingw w64devkit-1.21.0 gdb is compiled without python. Gnu Gdb-13.1